# Redirect to different page from inside c:import

Tags: java, spring, jsp, jstl

Is there any way I can redirect to a different page from a Spring Controller that gets called from a JSP using `<c:import>`?

Scenario is as follows: I have a Spring WizardFormController, that handles a multi-page form and is included into the website using a JSP and `<c:import>`. After the wizard is finished, I would like to redirect to a different page, but that seems to be impossible from the Controller. At least, if I could get a message to the surrounding JSP, it would already help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems, the only way is to use JavaScript to create a client-side redirect like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript>
    window.location.href = '<URL of Target>';
</script>
```

Comment: It would have been nice, if whoever downvoted this, had left a comment explaining why and possibly pointed out a better solution.